# Get MYSQL update notification on Android

Tags: android, mysql, push-notification, android-service, android-notifications

How can I send notifications to the user on every update in remote database. I want to notify user, if there is any new row added or updated existing one. I'm using a custom ListView and want to display BigPictureStyle notification.

```
public class EventServices extends Service {
int numMessages = 0;
String rowCount = null;
int oldRowCount = 0;
HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

String rowCountLink = "http://192.168.0.101/getdbrowcount.php";

public EventServices() {

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service was Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    oldRowCount = Integer.parseInt(getRowCount());

}



@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

    Log.d("Parse","Old row count: "+ oldRowCount);
    Log.d("Parse","New row count: "+Integer.parseInt(getRowCount()));


    if(Integer.parseInt(getRowCount())> oldRowCount) {


        String newEventLink =  "http://192.168.0.101/getnewevent.php";

        new MyTask(newEventLink).execute();
        //  NewEventDetails newED = new NewEventDetails();
        // NewEventHashMap newEventHashMap = new NewEventHashMap();


        String name = hashMap.get("name");
        String description = hashMap.get("description");
        String image = hashMap.get("image");

        Log.d("Parse","New event name: "+name);
        Log.d("Parse","New event description: "+description);
        Log.d("Parse","New event image: "+image);



        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ItemDetailActivity.class);
         resultIntent.putExtra("description",description);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated
        int notifyID = 9001;

        mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(name)
                .setContentText(description)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        // Set pending intent


    //    startActivity(resultIntent);
      //  mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent()
        mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        // Set Vibrate, Sound and Light
        int defaults = 0;
        defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        mNotifyBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);
        // Set the content for Notification
        //  mNotifyBuilder.setContentText(intent.getStringExtra("intntdata"));
        // Set autocancel
        mNotifyBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        // Post a notification
        mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
        oldRowCount++;

    }else{

    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}


private String getRowCount(){

    RowCountDownloader rowCountDownloader = new RowCountDownloader(rowCountLink);

    try {
        rowCount   = rowCountDownloader.execute().get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  //  Log.d("Parse","Rowcount in services: "+rowCount);
    return  rowCount;
}


class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,String> {

    String newEventLink;
   // HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();




    public MyTask( String newEventLink){
        this.newEventLink = newEventLink;

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String data = downloadData();

        return  data;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {


    }

    private String downloadData() {
        String line = null;
        InputStream inputStream =null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(newEventLink);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            if (br != null) {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
            } else {
                return null;
            }
            try{
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
                JSONArray ja = jo.getJSONArray("result");
                JSONObject obj = ja.getJSONObject(0);

                hashMap.put("name",obj.getString("name"));
                hashMap.put("description",obj.getString("description"));
                hashMap.put("image",obj.getString("image"));


           }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }catch(MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(inputStream!=null){
                try{
                    inputStream.close();
                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
      }
    }





  }
```

Whenever a new service is created it fetches total number of row (COUNT(*) from table) and then stores in the variable and then next time service checks for updated row counts from php script and then compares it with the existing row count. 
If new row count is greater then existing one then it will fetch the data from database (SELECT * from table where id = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table)). It will return new row only and then diplays notification.

but my problem is it is showing notification before it new data from the remote database. May be because I'm downloading images from the server. So, how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after lots of research I have solved this problem. I put all the code to download the data within doInBackground() and then passed the result in onPostExecute where I have displayed it on Notification.